# C++ Array passing and returning

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int* insertionSort(int* a);

int main()
{

  int a[5];
  for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
    cin>>a[i];
  }
  int b[5];
  *b = insertionSort(a);
  for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
    cout<<b[i]<<" ";
  }

}

int* insertionSort(int* a)
{
  for(int i=1;i<5;i++)
  {
    int key=a[i];
    int j=i-1;
    while(j>0 && a[j]>key)
    {
      a[j]=a[j+1];
      j-=1;
    }
    a[j+1]=key;
  }

  return a;
}
```

So this is my code for insertion sort. But when I run this it gives me the error

> insertionSort.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>   insertionSort.cpp:15:21: error: invalid conversion from ‘int*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
>      *b = insertionSort(a);

I would like to know how does passing and returning arrays in functions work in C++. What is the error in my code?

P.S : It may happen that my insertion code may be wrong. I have not really tested it so pardon me I could not check it because of this error. It would be really helpful if someone can explain it in detail.

Comment: Arrays are not pointers, and pointers are not arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`insertionSort` is returning a `int` pointer, and you're trying to assign it to an `int` by dereferencing the pointer (`*b`). The correct syntax would be

```
b = insertionSort(a);
```

Also, `b` should be declared as `int* b`

P.S., this compiles, but still doesn't work as intended, but that's a whole different question from the one you posed.

Comment: But this is definitely not what you want. Just make your function returning nothing (`void`) as you will already have the sorted array present at the address `a`. Also you will change the address of `b` without freeing the memory at `b` before.

Comment: Using this i get another error error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘int*’ to ‘int [5]’
   b = insertionSort(a);

Comment: I just wanted to learn @Shadow to return and pass arrays so used such a code

Comment: That is totally legit, @SarfrazBaig. But Federico is not really helping you because he just looks at the error without considering the whole code.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘int*’ to ‘int [5]’ b = insertionSort(a);

Comment: @SarfrazBaig you should also declare `b` as `int* b`

Comment: @Shadow you are totally right. And his solution is giving new error

Comment: @SarfrazBaig but you are aware of that now both `a` and `b` are pointing to the same address? This is no good style at all...

Comment: @Shadow I am working on to write better code. Thanks for pointing out the mistake

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm> // sort
#include <iostream>

constexpr size_t size {5};

std::array<int, size>* insertionSort(std::array<int, size>& a)
{
    std::sort(a.begin(), a.end());
    return &a;
}

int main()
{
    std::array<int, size> a {1, 4, 3, 2, 5};
    std::array<int, size>* b = insertionSort(a);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        std::cout << (*b)[i] << std::endl;
}
```

- You should use the standard library functions when possible ([here the sort one](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/))
- Thanks to C++11 we know have [array](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/) (instead of playing with raw pointers)